# Using $_server['document_root'] on localhost/the wild web

Tags: php, localhost, root, server-variables

On my WAMP setup, I'm using `$_server['document_root']` in a number of filepaths..
I had been using a static `$ROOT` variable, but thought it would be nice not to have to edit that constant when uploading the site.

Unfortunately, on my WAMP setup, `$_server['document_root']` is being defined as `'C:/wamp/www/'` and none of the links seem to be working under WAMP on Windows (though they were fine on MAMP on Mac when I initially made the change). It's looking in `file:///C:/wamp/www`.

I had read an article that was espousing the virtues of document_root for security reasons and ease of use. Is it really recommended, though? It occurs to me that it could be something different depending on the installation.

I'm thinking of just defining the document_root variable, but now I'm wondering whether it's reliable to use the variable at all.

Comment: I, instead of depending on doc root, define a variable/constant named apppath which basically holds the doc root for my web app and then use that variable/constant in my code , this makes it easy to move the web app to any place I want.

Comment: Your question lacks any hints of what the actual problem now is. If your server is misconfigured *or you actaully move the files around into a subdirectory, not below the docroot*, then using those CGI environment variables is indeed not practicable.

Comment: the problem right now is that document_root on this setup seems to be defined as C:/wamp/www and none of my headers are working bc it's looking in file:///C:/wamp/www

Comment: Damon, I think you need to see my answer, research Apache [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) configuration and learn how to change the configuration for Apache's virtualhost for the site you're having trouble with through WAMP.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13395074/1066234

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have experience with WAMP, but do have experience with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and alternatives. I've found `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to be the most reliable relative path to work from in an application.

The Reserved Variables documentation has quite a few comments on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` related to windows *(most specifically to IIS though, not WAMP)*

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php#45229

It sounds to me like your `DocumentRoot` for your site is pointing to `C:/wamp/www/` and not the subfolder for your domain within `www/`. You can learn about Apache's DocumentRoot [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot).

Comment: That all makes sense.  I'm having a heck of a time figuring out what exactly is going on. It is something to do with the pathing on my hd vs the pc

Comment: How to configure WAMP to do what I'm suggesting above is perhaps a question better asked in [[wamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wamp)].

Comment: seems so. i've put it back to just relative paths w/o any server variables for now since that was working.

Comment: Doing `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` will show that it is indeed `C:/wamp/www/`