# what is the purpose of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: php

I am reviewing code for my understanding in that at the start of PHP file there is  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. I am curious that in that page header must be included because header has scriat.js and bootstrap links and that PHP file using jquery and bootstrap classes, but I have not seen header file included in that PHP file, instead of that bellow lines are added

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/timetable/class.database.php";
include_once($path);
```

So does it mean all the files from the root are added in that PHP file?

Comment: Where is your code? Don't post it as an image, post it as plain text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP $\_SERVER\['DOCUMENT\_ROOT'\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394924/php-serverdocument-root)

Comment: thank you Barmar for your reply, I elaborate my question, I have a PHP file, in that file, I am using bootstrap classes and jquery code(that is present in the script.js file) but not included these files in my PHP file. so  $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; is including all files

Answer (score 3):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is the pathname that corresponds to the `/` directory of URLs on your webserver. So if `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is `/var/www`, and someone goes to `https://www.yourdomain.com/foo/bar`, they're fetching the file `/var/www/foo/bar`.

Comment: Thanks brother for reminding this in easy example to remember!. Got stuck at the moment. (although I am an experienced programmer)