# Use of DOCUMENT_ROOT

Tags: php, html

Got a straange - but simple - problem. The problem is that the CSS file won't load, despite path being correct.

I'm doing a website, and using php to insert link to css in page body.

This line produce the path to css-files.

```
$css_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/html/'.filename($title).'_id'.$id.'.css';
```

From resulting page source:

```
<link href="/customers/8/1/f/mattemannen.no/httpd.www/html/hva-er-matematikk_id5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Which reads correct to me, but css won't load.

I have an fully analogous setup for including html-files, which works fine.

However, If I use

```
$css_path = './html/'.filname($title).'_id'.$id.'.css';
```

instead of DOCUMENT_ROOT the CSS code loads.

Which brakes my code at another place btw.

Shouldn't DOCUMENT_ROOT give a valid path regardless of where code runs from?

**EDIT**:

**CONCLUSION: I MIXED TWO PATHS, OF THE PHP-CODE AND THE HTML-CODE. THEY ARE DISTINCT. ITS OKAY TO BE NOOB THANKS :)

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394924/php-serverdocument-root

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is a file system path. Your web server's public base path is likely to be just `/`.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Made an edit to document the suggestions. I would believe **II** should work. Its almost as if I can't believe it.

As far as I can see, DOCUMENT_ROOT, HTTP_HOST and "/" all produce valid paths. However, it won't consistently load.

Comment: File system paths like `/usr/bin` or `C:\Windows` cannot be used to read stuff over the network. They're different things.

Comment: All is happening on a server. All files on same computer. 

I think the basic question is whether a functionality alá ~/ for home folder in linux, is available. In this example, the files I need to reference, is in the ~/html folder. 

And - I really don't understand how come the above code isn't working, for instance why using 'prefix' DOCUMENT_ROOT only works in some contexts.

Comment: What I'm trying to explain is that the technologies involved to read files in your own computer are different that those used to browse the internet and so differ the semantics.Both `webmaster@example.com` and `123, Main St.` are mail addresses but you cannot send postcards to the former or email messages to the latter.

Comment: This question must have been answered before. Am I looking at it wrong, the Linux home folder analogy.

Comment: Edited in the conclusion. Looks like I've been trying to do something impossible. Have to admit, I'm still a little confused about why using 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' as a '~' won't work.